# Disable button in Tkinter (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

[image]

Hi , I have some question to ask

I just want to disable the button when i start my program

in attached image, it looks like the button is already disabled ,but its response to my click event or keyboard event

What should i do ?

Thank you for all answer

```
from Tkinter import *


def printSomething(event):
    print("Print")

#Start GUI
gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("800x500")
gui.title("Button Test")

mButton = Button(text="[a] Print",fg="#000",state="disabled")

mButton.place(x=5,y=10)

mButton.bind('<Button-1>',printSomething)
gui.bind('a',printSomething)

gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please add the code.

Comment: @TaohidulIslam i already add

Comment: In your code `mButton = Button(text="[a] Print",fg="#000",state="disabled")`, the button state is provided as disable, that's the reason for it being disable, what are you expecting exactly?

Comment: @SuryaTej  it look like disable but not , it still response to my click

Comment: @SuryaTej its still working :(

Comment: I believe its because the bind method. when you comment it out and run, even after clicks it wouldn't respond.

Comment: @SuryaTej oh, it's working now //and how can i use keyboard event without bind method ?

Comment: The usual way of configuring a function to be called on a button click is using `command=function` in the declaration of the button. This functionality *is* automatically disabled when using `state=disabled`. Any reason for manually binding to `<Button1>` instead of using `command=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `unbind` the event. `state="disabled"`/`state=DISABLED` makes button `disabled` but it doesn't `unbind` the event. You need to `unbind` the corresponding `events` to achieve this goal. If you want to enable the button again then you need to `bind` the event again. Like:

```
from Tkinter import *

def printSomething(event):
    print("Print")

#Start GUI
gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("800x500")
gui.title("Button Test")

mButton = Button(text="[a] Print",fg="#000",state="disabled")

mButton.place(x=5,y=10)

mButton.bind('<Button-1>',printSomething)
mButton.unbind("<Button-1>") #new line added
gui.bind('a',printSomething)

gui.mainloop()
```