# Disable windows Key when in full screen

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having a hard time trying to figure this out and am stuck on this but the run down is I put this Tkinter gui in full screen and I need to disable the windows key when the window is open. It is for my own lock screen I am making.

```
# Imports
import tkinter
import time
import datetime
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *
import keyboard
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller




def func1():

# Screen

Screen = tkinter.Tk()
Screen.title('Force Login')
Screen.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
Screen.configure(background='black')


var = StringVar()
label = Label( Screen, textvariable=var, relief=RAISED )

var.set("Hey!? How are you doing?")
label.pack()




Screen.mainloop()





def func2():
  while True:
 keyboard.wait("cmd")
 mouse = Controller()
 mouse.move(999, -999)
 time.sleep(0.30)
 mouse.press(Button.left)
 mouse.release(Button.left)






if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = func1).start()
    Thread(target = func2).start()
```

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/50795718/11225821 ?

Comment: No that is not what I mean i'm talking about stopping people from using the windows key but thanks!